# tcolorbox Theorem environment doesnt show first character

Tags: tcolorbox, theorems

I was going to use tcolorbox theorem environment using a guide on this [stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342313/how-do-i-add-a-colored-box-around-my-theorems). In the example there, it is good. However when I tried it myself, it always didnt show the first character (so I need to put Enter or {}).

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem
[]
{define}
{Definition}
{
colback = blue!5,
colframe = blue!35!black,
fonttitle = \bfseries
}
{def}

\begin{document}

\begin{define}{Test 1}
Test abcd
\end{define}

\end{document}
```

and here is my result

[image]

Can somebody help me? I know the problem were minor, but I want to know the correct way of using tcolorbox theorem environment. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Its expecting anohter madatory parameter -- used as a label. So using `\begin{define}{Test 1}{}` should fix it.

Comment: @PeterGrill Yeah that solved it, thanks! What is the second parameter supposed to be??

Comment: The second mandatory parameter is the label name. In your example, every `define` environment is labeled with `def:<2nd arg>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `define` environment specified via `\newtcbtheorem` requires two mandatory parameters, both of which can be empty `{}`. The first is the title and the second is the `<marker>` used as a `\label` and can be referenced via `\ref{def:<marker>}`:

[image]

Including the `hyperref` package makes the reference a link. You can also use the `nameref` package for more options.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtcbtheorem
[]
{define}
{Definition}
{
colback = blue!5,
colframe = blue!35!black,
fonttitle = \bfseries
}
{def}

\begin{document}

\begin{define}{Test 1}{Test Theorem Label}
Test abcd
\end{define}

As per theorem \ref{def:Test Theorem Label}, we see that
all our problems are now solved.

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer!