# Custom numbering of cbtheorem

Tags: tcolorbox, counters

Consider the following code:

```
% Equations and theorems style
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{%
  \thesection.%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \arabic{subsection}.\fi
  \arabic{equation}%
}
\newtheoremstyle{break}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}%
  {\upshape}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}%
  {\newline}{}%
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{cor}[equation]{Corollary}
```

Now, when I create theorems and corollaries, they follow the numbering of subsections and at each creation, the counter is incremented:

```
\section{Hey}
\subsection{Hey hey}

\begin{thm}[Theorem]
\end{thm}

\begin{cor}[Corollary]
\end{cor}

\begin{thm}[Theorem]
\end{thm}
```

[image]

Now, I would like to:

- color my theorems
- keep the same numbering system
- reformat my existing .tex file with minimal effort

To do so, I wanted to use [tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342313/how-do-i-add-a-colored-box-around-my-theorems), and create two environments `thm, cor` that would "override" the old ones. I set it up just like in the provided link, the winning answer, calling the environments `thm, cor` (see edit).

This is not working well though:

- I am unable to specify the numbering of tcolorbox, how to do so?
- I used to put `\label{}` commands below my theorems, this is now throwing an error with tcolorbox:  Argument of \GTS@CdrTwo has an extra }.

  \par
  l.10 \label{a_label}

Could anybody please help and possibly provide a way out of the errors? Thanks!

---

*Edit*

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-kZjpMtdlFoTxsBDgc3sqoFsgUzbsJNV/view?usp=sharing) you find a MWE of the code I'd like to reformat, and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_GfY00B3AxB-_BLt0FIbeWMA3xVPeQQs/view?usp=sharing) my attempt.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @dexteritas Is a MnonWE also okay? My code will note compile

Comment: If your question is about an specific error in the example, that is also ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `\tcolorboxenvironment`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

% Equations and theorems style
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{%
  \thesection.%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \arabic{subsection}.\fi
  \arabic{equation}%
}
\newtheoremstyle{break}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}%
  {\upshape}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}%
  {\newline}{}%
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{cor}[equation]{Corollary}

\tcolorboxenvironment{thm}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black}
\tcolorboxenvironment{cor}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black}

\begin{document}


\section{Hey}
\subsection{Hey hey}

\begin{thm}[Theorem]
Some text
\end{thm}

\begin{cor}[Corollary]
Some text
\end{cor}

\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{thm}[Theorem]
Some text
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the options in the second argument to suit your taste.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This looks perfect, although the provided code doesn't compile: I receive the error ! Undefined control sequence.
\tcolorboxenvironment #1#2->\AddToHook
{env/#1/before}{\begin {tcolorbox}[sa...
l.85 ...colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black}

Comment: @carmelo You probably have to update your TeX distribution

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote, your answer was exactly what I needed, thanks.